# Django SendGrid not sending email when attaching a template to email

Tags: django, sendgrid

When I send an email with no template I receive the email just fine. When I add an id for the template I don't get any errors but don't receive the email either. The template is set to active. I have my SENDGRID_API_KEY in my settings file. I know it must be something really stupid but cant seem to get it working. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Template id in the code below is masked so not what the actual code looks like.

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives


def emailSendGrid(self):
    mail = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        subject="Your Subject from sendGrid",
        body="SendGrid sent This is a simple text email body.",
        from_email="m@test.com",
        to=["martin@test.com"],
        headers={"Reply-To": "m@test.com"}
    )
    # Add template
    mail.template_id = '##############################'

    # Replace substitutions in sendgrid template
    # mail.ad = {'testTag': 'Test email sent from sendgrid with new content'}
    mail.send()
```

Comment: Please show the relevant configuration from `settings.py`, and say what (if any) packages you have installed to use sendgrid.

Comment: Settings.py added
EMAIL_BACKEND = "sgbackend.SendGridBackend"
SENDGRID_API_KEY = "key"

When I send an email as per above code the email is sent if I comment out the mail.template_id. But when I add the mail.template_id  back in nothing happens. No errors and no email.

installed Django-sendgrid

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Ended up being a stupid problem. The company has several api keys that I wasn't aware. Template was assigned to a different api key. Apologies